# Is there EXISTS subquery flattening in PostgreSQL in the new version?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-9.3

I found an old [discussion](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/25339.1174686582@sss.pgh.pa.us) that said PostgreSQL does not have subquery flattening optimization.

How about the newest versions? I did not find any official documentation about this.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I guess it does. (confession: I am a EXISTS() addict) BTW: the link is from 2007. BTW2: check the query plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is not a practical problem, I just want to understand the query optimizer.

Comment: Then look at the execution plan as wildplasser suggested

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and there has been for ages. For the exact version you'll need to check the git commit history.